# Getting Host IP on Client

Tags: android, server, client, wifi, chat

I am developing a wifi chat app for android where one phone creates a hotspot and acta as a client , and the other one uses wifi and acts as server.
I am getting the IP Address of the Server phone dynamically but i want to get the IP Address of Server phone dynamically on Client phone i.e IP of wifi Connected phone on a Hotspot activated phone programatically.
Is there a way around to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: Android hotspots usually have the same ip. Which one has yours?

Comment: Android has wifiP2p manager, maybe you can try that

Comment: @greenapps  I know that , bt The problem is i want to get IP Address of Wifi connected Client on Hopspot Server.

Comment: That is a different goal as mentioned in your post. Why did you change it?

Comment: i didnt get u properly .. bt i hve clearly mentioned that i want to get IP Address of Host programatically on Client Phone .  @greenapps

Comment: Yes. And also `i want to get IP Address of Wifi connected Client on Hopspot Server. `. Which is different. So what is it that you want? Why do you confuse us so?

Comment: hmmm ok my mistake..... didnt realise it.... i will modify the question... Please if u could help me in any way , that will be most appriciated ...n thnx for correcting me  @greenapps

Comment: Android hotspots usually have the same ip. Which one has yours?

Comment: 192.168.43.1 ...... but i want to get the IP address of server so that i can connect with it , how to get that ?